# Crossing at a sensor-controlled traffic light on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, vehicles-transportation, electricity

May one cross at a sensor-controlled traffic light on Shabbat / Yom Tov. I.e. - the light turns green only when it senses there is a pedestrian? Would it matter if it would be dangerous to cross anywhere else on that street other than where the light is?

Comment: Like all electricity-on-the-Sabbath-related questions, this one can only really be answered by a rav who is also an electrical engineer and is familiar with the exact device in question. It would definitely matter if it were dangerous to cross elsewhere.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/23342/electronic-sliding-doors-on-shabbat | http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4219/walking-past-motion-detector-sensor-activated-lights-on-shabbat