# Electronic card readers to enter buildings on Shabbat?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work, electricity, college-university-school

As a student, I've noticed that practically all of the dormitories in my university require residents to tap their student cards to a sensor before they are allowed to enter their building. (Moreover, some buildings even use electronic room keys, but it seems (to my non-Jewish mind) that the situation for that specifically might be covered by something like [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/48165/8555).)

Am I right in assuming that taking such an action would be forbidden on Shabbat, since it involves manipulation of electronic devices? If so, have any recommendations been made for such situations (particularly since it doesn't sound like a good idea to simply wait outside for a Gentile to unlock the door in the dead of winter)?

Comment: Update, since I was bored enough to do some more research: it looks like while some universities are willing to make accomodations and give keys to students, others straight-out refuse to.

Comment: Interesting question. Since in many cases, there is a slight delay between the key scan and the door opening, wouldn't this be a case of *grama* which may allow the key to be used?

Comment: "others straight-out refuse to" - I'm no lawyer, but you may want to seek legal counsel on this. It may be a case of unwillingness to provide reasonable accommodations for religious purposes (i.e. - religious discrimination). Offhand, sounds similar to cases where colleges fail to provide reasonable accommodations for handicapped.

Comment: @DanF There's also a slight delay from when I pour water out of a bucket to when it lands on the campfire. Is that permitted on Shabbat?

Comment: Isn't this question a dupe of the one you linked to with the hotel key? They're both electronic devices.

Comment: @DanF: I'm assuming that there might be a slight difference in the issues involved (but I'm not sure?) - being stranded in a hotel lobby isn't quite the same as being stranded outside a building.

Comment: "being stranded in a hotel lobby isn't quite the same as being stranded outside a building". I missed that nuance. I.e., perhaps if you're standing in the rain outside, there may be a greater "need" allowing more leniency? Wow. I guess Shomer Shabbat living in a college dorm is getting a lot more challenging these days! Maybe the only "kosher" way to get to you room on Shabbat is to leave the window open and climb through the window! Then, you have to be sure the ladder is propped up against the window before Shabbat, if there's no eruv.

Comment: Get yourself a chain with a padlock, create some way of keeping the door ajar but unable to enter without unlocking the padlock. Put the key to the padlock on a Shabbat belt if there is no eruv.

With regards to a hotel on Shabbat, when I was in that situation I followed a non-Jew in through the electronic door.

Comment: @DanF, I have had this problem before. The key I was given for my dorm in the beginning of the year wasn't working, although that turned out to be because of the lock never being used. B"H, my university is very accommodating.

Comment: Here's a guide to dealing with Shabbat accessibility issues in college - including dorm access: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1h5OEI3tFGmWE42meEvB0X9Tcd5V8MMQzohkSf3Xpi1U/

Answer (score 1):

A competent rabbi should be consulted in all such cases.

A similar case is discussed [here](http://www.kipa.co.il/ask/show/198284) where the questioner wants to know what to do if he's in a hotel where the rooms are accessed by a **magnetic** card. The rabbi answers that he should ask the hotel staff for a conventional key. If that fails, he can ask a non-Jew to open the door for him (since one is permitted to ask a non-Jew in cases of "great need".)

See also Rabbi [Yuval Sherlow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuval_Cherlow)'s [opinion](http://shut.moreshet.co.il/shut2.asp?id=40707), and Rabbi [Yitzchak Zilberstein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yitzchok_Zilberstein)'s [more stringent opinion](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49108&&pgnum=523).

Comment: My wife and I were on a cruise ship which included Shabbos and were advised to tape the card over the latch so that the door could not lock. However, this was only to the door of the cabin. Also since there would be no eruv on the campus, one would not be allowed to carry the card outsinde in any case.